# Arduino Vin in is not giving the desired output voltage

Tags: arduino-uno

Hey I am making a project on DC cooling fan with temperature sensing but I used a 5v cooling fan and connected the whole thing to the Vin by giving an output from the 5v supply but I still can't make the motor to rotate at its full speed.

I tried plugging the output in Vin and then tried to make the whole thing again but it just don't work.

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
const int potPin = A0;
const int fanPin = 3; // Connect the fan to this pin
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2); // Set the LCD address and dimensions
void setup() {
  dht.begin();
  pinMode(fanPin, OUTPUT);
  lcd.init();                      // Initialize the LCD
  lcd.backlight();                 // Turn on the backlight
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Temp Fan Control");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("by Your Name");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
}
void loop() {
  int threshold = map(analogRead(potPin), 0, 1023, 20, 40); // Map potentiometer value to temperature range
  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  if (temperature > threshold) {
    digitalWrite(fanPin, HIGH); // Turn on the fan
  } else {
    digitalWrite(fanPin, LOW); // Turn off the fan
  }
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Temp: ");
  lcd.print(temperature);
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Threshold: ");
  lcd.print(threshold);
  lcd.print("C");
  delay(1000);
}
```